# ItemSelected on ListView and more information about the object (Xamarin.Forms, C #)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem. In my xamarin.forms application I have a listview that gets as a source:

```
var tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(content);
myList.ItemsSource = tr.cars;
```

Classes for this data:

```
public class Items
{
    public List<Car> cars { get; set; }
}
public class Car
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public Owner owners { get; set; }
}
public class Owner
{
    public int o_id { get; set; }
    public string o_surname { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to view more information by clicking on an object in the listview. I use this in xaml ItemSelected="OnSelection" and in code:

```
void OnSelection(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
        Car myitem = sender as Car;
        DisplayAlert("ItemSelected", $"{myitem.company.ToString()}", "Ok");
        }
```

This give me error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I found some information about item selected, but none solved my problem.

Comment: use e.Item to get selected item eg:- Car myItem = e.Item as Car;

Comment: @HamidShaikh Unfortunately, this solution also gives the same error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: share your xaml code

Comment: please also share part of your JSON file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to get the item via `sender` for your reference.

**Change:**

```
Car myitem = sender as Car;
```

**To:**

```
Car myitem = (Car)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ItemTappedEventArgs` contains a reference to your item

```
void OnSelection(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    Car myitem = e.Item as Car;
    DisplayAlert("ItemSelected", $"{myitem.company.ToString()}", "Ok");
}
```